# Python programming without loops

Tags: python-3.x, loops

I have a list of clients who usually call (like in a support call center) asking about different topics.
I want to know if these clients, grouped per client (ins_no), have called in the last 30 days about the same topics.
I working with a 10 million records dataset and I need to do this without loops.

Can anyone help please?

This is an example of what I have

[image]

And what I need

[image]

I use CSV text file and I use python with its libraries (pandas,numpy...)
Thank you

Comment: Why can't you use loops? That's a huge restriction that seems rather pointless.

Comment: I can't use loops due to high data volume and low capacity of my computer

Comment: Not using loops won't make the data smaller or your computer faster.

Comment: It sounds like you're saying that your previous attempts have been slow or crashed, and that you've decided that somehow loops are the problem. If that's the case, then it is probably NOT the case that loops are the problem. Please post the existing code that you have tried and describe what your problem is.